# Pointing my domain name to my home PC

Tags: dns, bind, nameserver

I was previously paying for a VPS but have decided to setup a home server instead to save money.

I have a static ip address `12.34.56.78` and have registered a domain name `mydomain.com`.

I am running CentOS and have BIND running (I setup a Virtual Host for `mydomain.com` using VirtualMin, which also setup all the BIND nameserver entries for me).

The bit I am confused about is how to point my domain to my home server.  In my domain management section I can change the nameservers but don't seem to have access to any DNS configuration such as `A` records. What do I put into the nameserver entry?

When I was using the VPS they gave me the ns1 and ns2 entries, now I am running my own server I am a little confused.

Comment: Have you tried putting your static IP?

Comment: I thought about that but read somewhere that it has to be a name not an IP.  I will try it anyway.

Comment: I just tried it, the web interface told me that an error has occurred and would not let me change it to an IP address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your domain name provider should also have nameservers available for you to use.

The details will vary with provider, but essentially are:

1. Change the NameServers to "use our nameservers"
2. Wait (typically this step takes between 1 - 24 hours
3. Select "Change DNS settings" (or equivalent)

You should now have the ability to set your A and CNAME records, and will be able to add your static IP address.

Unfortunately, without knowing your specific provider, I can't provide more specific steps.

Comment: I am using iPage

Comment: According to http://www.ipage.com/knowledgebase/beta/article.bml?ArticleID=1776 I can change the DNS records.  Unfortunately, I don't have the DNS option when I login...Maybe that is because I am currently pointing to my VPS nameservers

Comment: I updated to use their nameservers, there is still no DNS option.  Maybe it will take 24 hours before it will display.  Does that make any sense?

Comment: PJC, if I am using their DNS Server, is there any reason for me to have BIND running on my home server?  I plan on hosting more than one domain which will point to different virtual hosts.

Comment: @jax If for all your domains you may use registrar servers, you don't need bind of your own.