# Reverse Proxy from my domain to my PC - How To?

Tags: windows-10, nginx, dynamic-dns, reverse-proxy

I am not asking this 'how to' as if its possible or as if a problem has developed. Many of the similar questions are looking for a solution or a way to extend it.

My question is more practical in nature.
Either I don't know what I am searching for so I am not getting the Google hits or yeah I guess I don't know what I am searching for.

I search for reverse proxy and I get a ton of pages but most are above my head or about web servers and load balancing.

Facts:
I have an account with ipage.com with two domain names that belong to me.

I have a NAS at home (running Windows  but I could use the WLS if I can be pointed to specific instructions) that I have setup a reverse proxy with using no-ip.com so when out and about I can log into my computer at home (without using ssh - for some reason ssh and my head don't mix)

I have to confirm the no-ip names monthly and after two years its becoming a drag. Now no-ip are moving to a subscription model so I need to use my domain name as I have already paid for that.

I would like to use my account at ipage.com to setup the reverse proxy but I cannot as the only thing I am allowed to do is ftp and sub domain . I am not allowed to run ssh or even install any application.

Next year I am moving to a vps but that is some 9 months away.

Is there a web page that gives me a step by step procedure so that I can setup a sub domain at ipage that connects to my pc at home?

- the domain name at ipage is companeros.com.

  My server at home is called hpz800 (very original) so `hpz800.companeros.com`

How can I setup hpz800.companeros.com to link to my HPZ800 at home? or is there a software that can do it? (I don't have static ip at home)

This question nearly worked but he has a static ip address and CentOS [Pointing my domain name to my home PC](https://superuser.com/questions/514539/pointing-my-domain-name-to-my-home-pc)

This guy knew what he was doing. Where do I setup the virtual host and what will it point to? ipage wont let me setup a virtual host unless I point it to a folder [Reverse Proxy for domain-name](https://superuser.com/questions/608674/reverse-proxy-for-domain-name)

This q [Nginx reverse proxy returns incorrect url](https://superuser.com/questions/890572/nginx-reverse-proxy-returns-incorrect-url) also knew what he was doing and I get the whole process apart from the second reverse proxy ubuntu - I don't understand the function of that and I don't know how to get to where he was.
][1](https://superuser.com/questions/514539/pointing-my-domain-name-to-my-home-pc)

I have already setup a Nginx web server at home and it works. I have it on both WLS and windows.

The solution has to replicate the no-ip solution where I type a web address and I login to my NAS. No ssh as most public pc will not allow it.

Is there a software I can install that will translate my ***hpz800.companeros.com*** to my ip at home (noting that that ip address changes daily)

I have ***Cyberghost*** on all my devices but I don't know how that helps.  I won't have cyberghost (vpn) on the pc outside my firewall.

The solution has to be able to translate my web address to my pc at home using say chrome or IE.

Comment: If you're willing to try to grok ssh, what you want is a reverse tunnel.  It's described well [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57688).  Set a reverse tunnel from home to your server, then you can use `ssh -D` to socks proxy from your pc to home, through your server.

Comment: I have vpn but how exactly does a vpn allow me to access a computer? Also the ssh solution cannot work (it says you must have shell access on both sites). I only have shell access on my pc but not from ipage. ipage allows only ftp access to a designated folder which can be the root but I cannot install ssh on ipage. Is there any software i can install on my pc that will allow me to access hpz800.companero.com if I install software on hpsz800.companero.com?

Comment: Reading your question again, i'm not totally clear on it, but (1) a domain is just a way of keeping track of your home machine's IP addr. If that's not changing, you don't need the domain name. You can just code it into your /etc/hosts file as something like "home.local" (2) To install the VPN server, you do need root on your home machine, then you use vpn client software on your laptop. You might [try this](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openvpn.html.en). (3) I gather ipage is some kind of hosting plan. For ssh, you need a shell account. Do they give you that? If not, try Webfaction.

Comment: I guess I have been assuming your home machine is stuck behind a firewall, and that you were having trouble getting to it, and so needed an outside server to act as a proxy.  Maybe you don't.  If you're not behind a firewall, you can just set up the VPN server/clent on the 2 machines and dispense with ipages.

Comment: @ Diagon I am behind a firewall. Problem is no-ip has moved to a subscription model so I need to do this fast. Again ipage is a hosting plan but shared hosting so no shell access. I can create a sub domain but I think I need an intermediate to link subdomain on ipage to pc at home. what is that intermediate? an application perhaps but where will it reside to carry out the " transaction"  it is that part that stumps me.

Comment: @Diagon: I have re-read all your comments but you assume I know what I am doing. I don't. Sorry. So far I know that on my home pc, I edit my host file to include hpz800.companeros.com to point to the server. That much I get. On ipage I setup the sub domain name hpz800 and attach it to companeros.com. That one I get. I don;t think ssh will be the answer because if I am out, on public pc, using ssh will be difficult as the software will not be installed and all my pc are windows. I have setup _Nginx_ and it works. How do I type hpz800.companeros.com in a web address outside and log into my pc?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're doing here, but if it's just a dynamic DNS that you're looking for, then the free one I use is http://freedns.afraid.org.  Perhaps that'll help you?

Comment: @Diagon: that was my first try. no matter what it will not reverse proxy on my pc. I still have the file and it still autostarts but I cant get it to run. I think I have solved this now. I used WSL, Nginx, Apache and Acrylic DNS